# Test management tool for Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, test-management, qtp

My company recently began migrating from using *QTP* to *Selenium webdriver*.  We are looking for a test management tool similar to *Quality Center* (what is *QTP* primaly for) that would work well with *Selenium*. We need a tool to schedule and run our tests.

Any suggestions for **free open source or other inexpensive tools**?

I've searched but have only seen old threads.
Thanks.

Comment: test runner like Jenkins is enough? Something with more features? Which features?

Comment: Our main features we need are Running Selenium tests unattended, Report testing results, and Defect tracking. Would Jenkins work for this?

Comment: Jenkins can run any script before or after execution and you could use any web api for loggin issues. Here is an example for QC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027445/creating-defects-in-qc-from-jenkins-when-build-fails

Answer (score 8):

I do not know what features QC delivers for running automated tests, but this is what I would do to maintain a Selenium test-suite:

As a test runner for Selenium just use a unit-test runner in the language you are developing your tests in. Most [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit)-tests runners generate the same result files, which can be parsed by [report generators](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) for reporting.

To schedule these test-runs I would advice using a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server, and to let all tests run on each commit/check-in in the source control system. (Understand which new code breaks what test, as soon as possible.)

For CI products look at:

- [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), open source.
- [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), commercial but with limited free version.
- For more systems look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software

Setup a digital wallboard to show the feedback of the CI server or let it send notifications by email or chat.

For more human readable test management that can easily be combined with Selenium look at these open source tools:

- [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)
- Or [jBehave](http://jbehave.org/)
- Or other [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) frameworks: https://dzone.com/articles/brief-comparison-bdd

Comment: Just want to add: As Jenkins is open source there are many tutorials for different languages out there and you'll get it fast to work. I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Niels answer that CI-Servers like Jenkins are the tool of choice for automated test execution (which I strongly support), I like to point out that there are also plugins available for transferring the test results from Jenkins to a full blown test management application for archiving and reporting as well as merging them with other test results as e.g. unit tests or manual test results.

One example would be the [Jenkins Klaros-Testmanagement Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Klaros-Testmanagement+Plugin) which adds a Build-Publisher to automatically transfer the results to [Klaros-Testmanagement](http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com) which is both available in a free Community Edition as well as a commercially supported version.

Disclaimer: I am working on both of these implementations

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget Serenity aka Thycidides (http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/)
It is in that sense a test management tool as it excels in creating a living test documentation for you which is also a great test report.
You can use it with JBehave or Cucumber or just with plain jUnit.
It depends on maven or grade to run the tests.

Comment: You meant gradle instead of grade?

Answer (score 1):

I also use Tosca Testsuite. I can create Execution lists, do distributed execution, link to our CI and have the risk contribution of the test case. and use the other features, like service virtualization, distributed execution and test case design.

http://www.tricentis.com/solutions/testing-with-selenium/

I am not sure if it actually does more than you ask for.
PS: You can find it among the sponsors of the Selenium project

Answer (score 1):

*We are looking for a test management tool similar to Quality Center*

I would actually suggest that the equivalent tool does NOT exist.
My experience over the past few years is that you have to pick the programming language and the test automation framework within that language.
Even with test frameworks though, you will still need to manually write the structure of the tests and test suites.  The test frameworks themelves do not specify or provide such an integrated tool.

The various answers about Jenkins (which would also apply to CircleCI my new favorite tool) do not apply in my opinion as they are about running an *already developed suite* using a continuous integration server.  CI tools themselves do not solve the test organization issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe TestRail can be edited to be able to spin off automated tests within the TestRail site.

See: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-custom/automation-trigger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a look at Open source options, here is a comprehensive link of such test management tools [Open Source Test Management Tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/testmgt.php)

Answer (score 0):

We are using Jenkins CI and TestRail. Also we have our own framework which makes reporting much more easy.

https://github.com/selenium-webdriver-software-testing/kspl-selenium-helper

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For test management we are primarily using google spreadsheets, we push the results from our test runs to the spreadsheet where we analyze it. Please check out this article [Managing Regression using spreadsheets](http://onpathtesting.com/manage-regression-testing-with-spreadsheets/)

There are also frameworks which provide reports like [Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/)